# Inject a custom component into a named slot in child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Lang.vue]

```
<Core ref="core">
    <template v-slot:passageOne>
        <p>This is passage One Content!</p>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:video>
        <myVideo ref="video"></myVideo>   <!--For Q2-->
    </template>
</Core>
```

[Core.vue]

```
<div>
    <slot name="passageOne"></slot>
    <slot name="video">GG</slot>  <!--The fallback text is GG-->
</div>
```

*myVideo is a self developed component

Q1: Is it possible to inject a custom component (myVideo in this case) into Core component's second slot? In my case, the fallback text "GG" is shown which meaning that inject unsuccessfully, but why?

Q2: If it is possible for Q1, is it possible to get reference object for myVideo component (the line commented with 'For Q2') in Lang.vue scope(Parent)?

Please provide an use case if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you shouldn't use html tags as vue component names, try to name it like `MyVideo`

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim Ok, let me modify my question. Do you have a use case showing it could work, please?

Comment: And also, how would you suggest for Q2?